# How to handle categories inside properties file?

Tags: java, properties

There is a new process to implement that involves writing and reading from an Excel file. For this, the process needs some properties to define the sheets and cells to use for write/read values. There is a fixed number of properties to use based on something we could say a category. To show an example:

```
category1.sheet1=Customer Info
category1.cell1=A10
category1.cell2=B10
category1.cell3=A20

category2.sheet1=Customer Data
category2.cell1=A20
category2.cell2=B20
category2.cell3=A25

//more categories...
```

In the process, at some step, I decide the category that I'm using and then I must consume the properties for that category only. How would I load the properties for a single category?

Currently, I have this approach (code simplified for better understanding):

```
//get category1 or category2 based on some rules...
String category = getCurrentCategory();
//define the name of the properties to use
String sheet1 = category + "sheet1";
String cell1 = category + "cell1";
String cell2 = category + "cell2";
String cell3 = category + "cell3";
//use the properties...
String sheet1Value = getProperty(sheet1);
String cell1Value = getProperty(cell1);

//excelFileHandler is a custom interface to work with Excel files
//it serves as facade to communicate with Apache POI classes
excelFileHandler.goToSheet(sheet1Value).goToCell(cell1Value).setValue("some value");
excelFileHandler.goToCell(cell2Value).setValue("some value");
```

Is there another approach to solve this kind of problem or should I keep this design?

Note: I'm in design phase so I can still change the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExtendedProperties` to filter by property prefix.

See [Commons Collections ExtendedProperties#subset()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties.html#subset%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: You could also read multiple values from one line if you separate them with comma. E.g. `category1.row1=10,20,,40,,60` and use `String[] values = extProp.getStringArray("category1.row1")` - this could save you a number of lines

Comment: I read about that power in the class, but that's not currently my problem, thanks anyway. I'll do some tests using the `ExtendedProperties#subset` before marking this as the answer.